# Network analysis library - example from PYQGIS developer cookbook does not work

Tags: pyqgis, network

I am using QGIS 2.6.  I'd like to be able to calculate the driving distance between any two geocoded locations (can't use the shortest path roads plugin because it appears to be interactive and I need to be able to read the geocoded coordinates from a list).

I found what I thought was it on the pyqis developer cookbook page:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html

When I simply copy the example over and try to run it I typically get the following error:

```
>>>>pStart = QgsPoint(-0.743804, 0.22954)
>>>>tiedPoint = director.makeGraph(builder, [pStart])
>>>>pStart = tiedPoint[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and the length of tiedPoints appears to be zero.

How can that be?